# Set 1st folder as variable batch file

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, directory

Hi how can I always get the 1st folder in a path to be a variable.
Sample

```
c:\A\B
c:\A\B\C
C:\A\B\C\D
```

and my variable will always be outputting the folder A because my bat is sometimes will be put deeper in A folder

Comment: I have no idea what's being asked here. What *variable* and how are you setting it and where and what are you *outputting*? And what does *1st folder in a path to be a variable* even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for /f` loop to split the var with delimiter `\` and get the 2nd token.

```
> For /f "tokens=2delims=\" %A in ("%__CD__%") Do @Echo %A
Users

> For /f "tokens=2delims=\" %A in ("%CD%.\") Do @Echo %A
Users

> Set "MyPath=X:\path\to\somewhere"
> For /f "tokens=2delims=\" %A in ("%MyPath%.\") Do @Echo %A
path
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this is what i was looking for ... but i did put an extra % dunno why one % is not working on %A

Comment: My examples are on the command line, in a batch the for variables need 2 percent signs. Sorry for not mentioning this.